# Django app: can I run management command that is defined in a dependency?

Tags: django, django-management-command

My Django application called `my_app` pulls in a dependency called `my_dependency`.
`my_dependency` declares a management command called `useful_thing`

Is there a way I can run `useful_thing` directly from `my_app`'s start.sh?

I've tried calling it directly but it's not found, but maybe there's a way I can configure it to look for management commands from a particular place? I'm new to Django and suspect this is not a sensible thing to try and do.

Comment: Make sure your dependency is added to INSTALLED_APPS, then the command should be found

Comment: Thank you this was the problem, I had the wrong name in installed_apps

Answer (score 0):

You can call any (properly defined) management command using Django's manage.py, just like any other Django command:

```
python manage.py userful_thing
```